# Open saved rtf document with MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have some code that exports queries and saves the document as a rich-text file:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "rptEvents", "RichTextFormat(*.rtf)", "C:\SARPCCO_Database\SARPCCO_Report.rtf"
```

How can I open the saved document wih the same export button?

The full code behind this button is:

```
    Private Sub CommandExport_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_CommandExport_Click

Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim strSql As String
'Dim rsCriteria As Recordset
Dim strWhere As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set strWhere = db.OpenRecordset("qryEvents", dbOpenDynaset)

'*** the first record in the Criteria table ***
strWhere.MoveFirst

'*** loop to move through the records in Criteria table
'Do Until strWhere.EOF
'*** create the Select query based on
' the first record in the Criteria table
strSql = "SELECT * FROM qryEvents WHERE "
strSql = strSql & "[Event_ID] = " & strWhere![Event_ID]

'*** delete the previous query
'db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryEvents2"
'Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("qryEvents2", strSql)
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "rptEvents", "RichTextFormat(*.rtf)", "C:\SARPCCO_Database\SARPCCO_Report.rtf"
Documents.Open Filename:="C:\SARPCCO_Database\SARPCCO_Report.rtf", ReadOnly:=False

strWhere.MoveNext
'Loop

Exit_CommandExport_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_CommandExport_Click:
    MsgBox "The file SARPCCO_Report you want to export to doest not exists." & vbCrLf & vbLf & _
"Please, ensure the file is in the right place before attempting to export your report", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Report exporting error"
    Resume Exit_CommandExport_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you GOOGLE, I found a working code:

Dim WordApp As Object

```
Dim WordDoc As Object

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\MyFiles\Test.rtf", ReadOnly:=False)
WordApp.Visible = True

'do your stuff
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a *True* for *AutoOpen*:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "rptEvents", "RichTextFormat(*.rtf)", "C:\SARPCCO_Database\SARPCCO_Report.rtf", True
```